# interpolation missing years R

Tags: r, data.table, interpolation

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c("A", "B","C"),
             T2010 = c(61, 40,NA), T2011 = c(8, NA,10),
             T2012 = c(NA, NA,NA), T2013 = c(10, 49,35))
```

Hi,
here is an example of data i would get (after a dcast).
I would like to impute the missing data (NA) with an interpolation only for points enclosed in two values.
For example here for ID=C, I do not want to interpolate T2010 (the same will be for the last year, when it is missing, I do not want to interpolate)
I am not sure function approx would work here.
Would somebody have an idea how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: a simple linear interpolation between the next two points would be fine. It means here for  A: 61 8 9 10, for B: 40 43 46 49, for C NA 10 22.5 35

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-3/topics/na.approx

Comment: Solution using `zoo`: `t(zoo::na.approx(t(dt[, 2:5])))`

Comment: Thanks both of you. will try on the full dataset.

Comment: Is there a way to retain the lines where the interpolation was done? Not all records are in my full dataset (which is normal).

Comment: `ans <- t(zoo::na.approx(t(dt[, 2:5]))); which( (is.na(ans) + is.na(dt[, 2:5])) == 1, arr.ind = T )`